# How to directly Print Myanmar Unicode Data to pos network printer?

Tags: php

The data directly print to Network Printer, but, it's not correctly printing unicode data. 
This is my code

```
<?php
include("confs/config.php");
$date=$_POST['date'];
$tbl=$_POST['table'];
$voucher=$_POST['voucher'];
$waiter=$_POST['waiter'];
$catg=$_POST['catg'];
$initialized = chr(27).chr(64);
$condensed1 = chr(15);
$condensed0 = chr(18);
$corte = Chr(27) . Chr(109);
$print_data  = $initialized;

$print_data="#wait"."\"\n"."#".$voucher."\"\n"."#".$waiter."\"\n";
$print_data.="စမ္းသပ္ထုတ္လုပ္ျခင္း ခ်က္ျပဳတ္ရန္ မလိုပ."\"\n"."#".$voucher."\"\n"."#".$waiter."\"\n";

try
{

$fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.87",9100);
fwrite($fp, $print_data);
fclose($fp);

echo 'Successfully Printed';

} 

    catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

[image: My Output]

Comment: You are probably missing UTF-8 encoding. utf8_encode($print_data);

Answer (score 0):

**Try  UTF-8 byte-order mark**

```
$print_data="#wait"."\"\n"."#".$voucher."\"\n"."#".$waiter."\"\n";
$print_data.="စမ်းသပ်ထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း ချက်ပြုတ်ရန် မလိုပ."\"\n"."#".$voucher."\"\n"."#".$waiter."\"\n";
$print_data = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$print_data; //utf8 bom
```